# Bootstrap is not working in HTML page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot seem to find the problem. I've changed the body contents with another website that functions perfectly and it works. No bootstrap elements are showing up despite trying to initialize them through both relative paths and CDN.

I've yet to do any CSS styling of my own so this is definitely a HTML issue that I cannot find. The brackets should all be closed properly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyJewlls</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="padding">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search.." />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="row" id="absolute">
                        <h1>MyJewlls</h1></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="lista">
                        <li>Log in
                            <li>
                                <li>Register
                                    <li>
                                        <li class="none">My wishlist
                                            <li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <a href="#home">Home</a>
                        <a href="#news">News</a>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="slajder">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- row-->
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina prva">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Jewellery</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="images/bella.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive " src="images/rings.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina druga">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Watches</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="images/bella.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive " src="images/rings.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="images/bella.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina treca">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Fragrances</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="images/bella.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <a href=""><img class="img-responsive " src="images/rings.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check browser console for any 404 errors

Comment: your code has 18 errors....check here https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: It is working fine when trying with CDN links from here: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your list items inside list with 'lista' id(line 26) is broken. You should close them properly.

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="lista">
        <li>Log in
          <li>
            <li>Register
              <li>
                <li class="none">My wishlist
                  <li>
      </ul>
```

Then you have some weird div closing div tags at line 49, 53 and 54.
Then you'd better use this link (it's from Bootstrap Official site)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

UPD:
And one more thing that I would suggest you to do is to place 'script' tags on the bottom of the 'body'. It will make rendering the page a little faster. 
So here is the final result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyJewlls</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="padding">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search.." />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="row" id="absolute">
            <h1>MyJewlls</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="lista">
            <li>Log in</li>
            <li>Register</li>
            <li class="none">My wishlist</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                   <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                   </button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="slajder">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- row-->
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina prva">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>Jewellery</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="padding">
        <div class="col-lg-7"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
        <div class="col-lg-5"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina druga">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>Watches</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="padding">
        <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina treca">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>Fragrances</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="padding">
        <div class="col-lg-5"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
        <div class="col-lg-7"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing Bootstrap 3 (css) and 4 (js). Either one or the other should be used.

Comment: Ah yeah, slipped out of my attention. Thanks for the mentioning

Answer (score 0):

The code seem fine, try to refresh the browser cache or use private mode ( CTRL+Shift+P on Chrome )

Kind Regards
M

Comment: It is definitely not the browser as I have checked tab by tab with another website that works perfectly...

Comment: try do hard reload - guides https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.Wp-6cujwaUk

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your bootstrap css link with this one `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyJewlls</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row" id="padding">  
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div  class="row" id="absolute"><h1>MyJewlls</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="lista">
                    <li>Log in<li>
                    <li>Register<li>
                    <li class="none">My wishlist<li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="navbar">
                 <a href="#home">Home</a>
                 <a href="#news">News</a>
                 <div class="dropdown">
                   <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
                   <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                   </button>
                   <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                   </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="slajder">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

            </div>
        </div>  <!-- row-->
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina prva">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h2>Jewellery</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-7"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina druga">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h2>Watches</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina treca">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h2>Fragrances</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-5"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-7"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you are fixing your bootstrap.css path (you can use the public url etc).

1. Import jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js. As bootstrap depends on it.
2. Seems  you are missing some bootstrap styling of your components. Please check my code snipped. I fixed your Navigation menu only, but you can get the idea.

Cheers!

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyJewlls</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
 
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row" id="padding">  
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div  class="row" id="absolute"><h1>MyJewlls</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="lista">
                    <li>Log in<li>
                    <li>Register<li>
                    <li class="none">My wishlist<li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
<!--NAVIGATION FIX START---->
   <div id="main_navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button  class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
       </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<!--NAVIGATION FIX START END---->
 </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="slajder">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

            </div>
        </div>  <!-- row-->
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina prva">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h2>Jewellery</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-7"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina druga">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h2>Watches</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="sredina treca">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h2>Fragrances</h2></div>
        <div class="row" id="padding">
            <div class="col-lg-5"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"src="images/bella.jpg" alt=""/><p>jdhydgefwgdggsgfvdsfsffdsg</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-7"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive "src="images/rings.jpg" alt=""/><p>mdnvnfhdhjcvjhsdggh</p></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```